# App didn't crash due to Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this) while working with a separate class that extends Application

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When I did as Parse guided for adding `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this)` in my MainActivity `onCreate()` (with fragments) it caused my app to crash when I was changing the orientation of the device.

My logcat:

```
06-02 12:13:07.036  14407-14407/com.example.android.donotbelateapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.donotbelateapp, PID: 14407
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.donotbelateapp/com.example.android.donotbelateapp.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`

  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
```

However when I added a separate class that extends `Application` and placed the following Parse-related code in it:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
```

the problem was resolved.

Why did I have to use those commands to make it work?

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting.
I think that you should add a link to the tutorial that you followed and add some relevant source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well, first, let me just read the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.donotbelateapp/com.example.android.donotbelateapp.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
```

Ok, so the error says that Parse.enableLocalDataStore() must be called before Parse.initialize().

Then, you create a class extending Application which you clearly use and in it call Parse.enableLocalDataStore(). Probably early in the application lifecycle, which means it gets called before your Activity calls Parse.initialize().

So, you're confused that when you fixed the problem, the problem was fixed. . .

Anyway, I was curious to see what "Parse guided for adding Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this) in my MainActivity" so I went to this page, helpfully titled ["Using the Local DataStore"](https://parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore). I then actually read through it. Under section 2, Enable the local datastore, it says (emphasis mine):

> TodoListApplication is also where we add in our Parse credentials, set
>   our default access controls, and set up our app to use Anonymous
>   Users, so that people can save todos locally without having to log in.
>   **Next, to enable the local datastore, simply add a call to
>   Parse.enableLocalDatastore() before our call to Parse.initialize()**: